# .htaccess rewrite url and removing .php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to remove the .php from the url through htaccess file. for example **home.php** to **home** I'm using the following rewrite rule in htaccess file.

```
  RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

and also I want to rewrite the url. for example

```
/detail.php?ca=38&title=rewrite uri sample
```

to

```
detail/article/38/rewrite uri sample
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try search to the entire www, then I have an answer..

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteRule    ^article/([0-9]+)/?$    detail.php?ca=$1    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^article/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    detail.php?ca=$1&title=$2    [NC,L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for Abdulla that I get the rewrite .php, and thanks to Starkeen to edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

For `GoDaddy`

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Your answer is incomplete, he also wants to remove query strings from urls.

Comment: If I can adding some question, can I change " " with "-" example detail/article/38/rewrite uri sample to detail/article/38/rewrite-uri-sample and how I get variable "38" and "rewrite uri sample" with simple php :) thanks