# Laravel redirect from index.php and index.html to domain

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner webdeveloper.
I have small problem with redirect.

I have this htacess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.pl [R=301,L]

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It's work fine.
Now I need redirect from https://domain.pl/index.php and https://domain.pl.html to https://domain.pl

I use Laravel 8.

How can I make it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess rewrite url and removing .php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952264/htaccess-rewrite-url-and-removing-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be

```
Route::get('/index.html', function(){ return redirect('http://domain/'); });
```